# Jquery Slider Set Value after Slide

Tags: jquery, slider, slide

I'm trying to set the value of slider in slide event. Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({

                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                step: 1, // Use this determine the amount of each interval
                values: [0], // The default range
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var slider = $("#slider").slider({
                        animate: true
                    });
                    slider.slider('value', 500);
                }
            });
        });
```

What am I missing? I can't seem to animate and set the value of the slider.

**Edit: Ok now I can set the value of the slider BUT it happens too fast. I want it to slowly go to the value I set. Here is my edited code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({

                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                animate: "slow",
                step: 1,// Use this determine the amount of each interval
               // values: [0] // The default range
               change: function (event, ui) {
                   $("#slider").slider('value', 500);
                }
            });
        });
```

How can i make it slowly move to 500 instead of setting it right away?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reference**:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zFsZV/)

After moving the slider button and releasing it, the slider button will animate back to a locked value.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        // Values "fast", "normal", "slow", or duration can be used.
        animate: 1500,
        step: 1,
        // Starting value is 500
        value: 500,
        animate: true,
        change: function(){
           // This setTimeout will allow the slider to animated correctly.
           setTimeout("$('#slider').slider('value', 500);", 350);
        }
    });

    // On page load, animate the slider to this value of 500.
    $('#slider').slider('value', 500);

});
```

---

**Status Update:** The SO Poster required the `stop:` event instead of the `change:` event in the UI Slider for other specific requirements, but there is no visual difference seen when that is used.

Comment: I don't need to get the value, I need to animate the sliders cursor to the value. Now I can set the value of the slider (i am updating my question after this) but can't move it slowly, cursor jumps to the value I set instantly.

Comment: Pabuc, my answer is now different. Please review the jsFiddle and tell me if this is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: i was able to solve my problem by using stop instead of change event of slider. You may edit your reply and I'll approve it.

Comment: I now have that explained in my Status Update section. Please note your solution of using `stop` is outside the scope of your SO Question since `change` does the same thing ***visually***. Any ***additional*** jQuery UI Slider requirements, e.g. timing values, variable names, etc., is based on your ***specific*** needs, but the point of the Answer with the method shown is the point here. There really isn't a need to force a "Answer re-write" if you've explained yourself in the comments how tweaking it for other code-related issues is the problem, unless `change:` paramenter was used illegally.